# Send data to php page with ajax

Tags: ajax, post

I have a bug actually with this code.

My JS code is the following:

```
<script>
var card_Name = "Tour Eiffel";
</script>
```

I send the data in ajax:

```
var myDatas = { card_Name: card_Name };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveContent.php",
    data: myDatas,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:  function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
});
```

In my PHP i get the element like this:

```
print_r($_POST['card_Name']);
```

But nothing is shown in the XHRs parts of my console...

Any idea why ?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you returning the result from your PHP file? Echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in HTML or PHP File .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){

        var card_Name = "Tour Eiffel";
        var myDatas = { card_Name: card_Name };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "saveContent.php",
            data: myDatas,
            cache: false,
            success:  function(data){
           alert(data);
          }
       });
    })
</script>
```

Don't include this in your ajax

```
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```

Comment: You would like I test your code, but I do not see any difference between your code and my question one...

Comment: You will have to explain me why those two lines make the thing? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Visit this site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax